# Piping tail output though grep twice

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, tail

Going with a typical Apache access log, you can run:

```
tail -f access_log | grep "127.0.0.1"
```

Which will only show you the logs (as they are created) for the specified IP address.

But why does this fail when you pipe it though `grep` a second time, to further limit the results?

For example, a simple exclude for ".css":

```
tail -f access_log | grep "127.0.0.1" | grep -v ".css"
```

won't show any output.

Comment: See also [double grep on tail -f gives no output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164681/20661)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that the first grep is buffering the output which means the second grep won't see it until the buffer is flushed.

Try adding the `--line-buffered` option on your first grep:

```
tail -f access_log | grep --line-buffered "127.0.0.1" | grep -v ".css"
```

For more info, see [*"BashFAQ/009 -- What is buffering? Or, why does my command line produce no output: `tail -f logfile | grep 'foo bar' | awk ...`"*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009)

Answer (score 13):

This is the result of buffering, it will eventually print when enough data is available.

Use the `--line-buffered` option as suggested by *Shawn Chin* or if `stdbuf` is available you can get the same effect with:

```
tail -f access_log | stdbuf -oL grep "127.0.0.1" | grep -v ".css"
```

Comment: Thanks Thor, your also correct, but I think Shawn got in there just before you.