# Command Linux not working "grep"

Tags: linux, grep

I'm using the command `grep` in Linux to get a specific information from my output file, but I don't know why does not copy to the file.

When I use the command like that, it works

```
udevadm monitor --env | grep "ACTION"
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
ACTION=remove
```

But, when I use the command like this, it does not copy to the "output.txt"

```
udevadm monitor --env | grep "ACTION" >> output.txt
```

Comment: This is because of buffering in the redirection, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13858912/1331399) to see how to get around it. Short answer: add the `--line-buffered` option to the `grep` command.

Comment: @ Thor thanks it's working now ...i just add the "--line-buffered" option like this , and it's working   udevadm monitor --env | grep --line-buffered "ACTION" >> file.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is correct. You must find the filtered lines in the end of `output.txt`.
You can add `tee` between to see what is copied.

```
udevadm monitor --env | grep "ACTION" | tee >> output.txt
```

Comment: thanks @Igor Chubin for you're quick reply....i used the command that you propose to me, but still not coping to the "output.txt"...
the file is still empty :s

Comment: but the output was not empty?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
udevadm monitor --env >> file ; cat file | grep "ACTION" >> result
```

tell me about file and result.

Comment: @ Dinou ..i used you're command, the two files are created ...in the first "file" i get all the information of the "udevadm monitor", but in the second file "result" nothing was copied to this file.

Comment: Can you type : `ll result` to know about the files rights...