# Why can't I filter tail's output multiple times through pipes?

Tags: sed, grep, pipe, tail

Unexpectedly, this fails (**no output**; tried in **sh**, **zsh**, **bash**):

`echo "foo\nplayed\nbar" > /tmp/t && tail -f /tmp/t | grep played | sed 's#pl#st#g'`

Note that two times **grep** also fails, indicating that it's quite irrelevant which commands are used:

```
# echo -e "foo\nplayed\nbar" > /tmp/t && tail -f /tmp/t | grep played | grep played
```

**grep** alone works:

```
# echo -e "foo\nplayed\nbar" > /tmp/t && tail -f /tmp/t | grep played
played
```

**sed** alone works:

```
# echo -e "foo\nplayed\nbar" > /tmp/t && tail -f /tmp/t | sed 's#pl#st#g'`
foo
stayed
bar
```

With **cat** instead of **tail**, it works:

```
# echo -e "foo\nplayed\nbar" > /tmp/t && cat /tmp/t | grep played | sed 's#pl#st#g'
stayed
```

With `journalctl --follow`, it fails just like with `tail`.

**What's the reason for being unable to pipe twice?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Piping tail output though grep twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858912/piping-tail-output-though-grep-twice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a buffering issue - the first grep buffers it's output when it's piping to another command but not if it's printing to stdout. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009 for additional info.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. The article suggests to first check if  there are unnecessary commands that may be eliminated. In my particular case, I was able to do that adding `--silent` and the explicitly printing substituted lines (`p`). Eg `sed --silent 's#pl#st#p'`. (Otherwise, the mentioned *unbuffered* variants would've been the way to go.)

Comment: I've never heard of `--silent`, looks like it does the same thing as the more common `-n`. That will print lines that contain `pl` in context other than `played` thought. You can do things like `/played/{s/pl/st/gp}` with sed though check the syntax. In awk it'd be `awk '/played/{gsub(/pl/,"st");print}'`.

Comment: Luckily my use case is more complex than the example I gave. Thus every line that receives substitutions is actually desired in the output. Still, for future cases I'd be curious about the correct syntax for sed. (Btw `--silent` *is* `-n`. I just prefer using the elaborate variants of switches when scripting and documenting.)