# tail -f (follow) and xargs

Tags: linux, bash

Why does tail -f not play well with xargs?

This command works as expected, I see a block of text:

`tail /var/log/auth.log|xargs echo`

But this command shows me nothing:

`tail -f /var/log/auth.log|xargs echo`

Both `tail` and `tail -f` have output.  One might think it is line terminators, but setting both to null did not work:

`tail -z -f /var/log/auth.log|xargs -0 echo`

Comment: Because `tail -f` doesn't terminate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `tail -f` doesn't terminate; it is still waiting for new lines to be added. And `xargs` (unless you use `-L` or similar) waits until it has "enough" arguments to make it worthwhile executing the command line.

If your intention was to execute the command once for each line, use `xargs -L1`. See [`man xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) for details:

> ```
>    -L max-lines
>          Use at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line.
>          Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued
>          on the next input line.  Implies `-x`.
> ```

Watch out for the "trailing blanks" behaviour. You can avoid that by using `-I` instead of `-L1` and specifying an explicit replacement argument:

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log | xargs -I {} echo {}
```

Comment: Any idea why the -f in tail breaks this command?  `tail -fz /var/log/auth.log | egrep -o failure |xargs -L1 echo \>` (with -f there is no output).

Comment: @jcalfee314: It's a very similar problem. `egrep` buffers its output so it doesn't write anything until it has "enough" to write (usually several thousand characters). You can use `stdbuf` to attempt to force `grep` to line-buffer. There are many duplicate questions on SO.

Comment: @jcalfee314: Here's the first one I found with an SO search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822898/why-cant-i-filter-tails-output-multiple-times-through-pipes/