# No output while piping tail through grep

Tags: bash

There is a file located at `$filepath`, which grows gradually. I want to print every line that starts with an exclamation mark:

```
while read -r line; do 
    if [ -n "$(grep ^! <<< "$line")" ]; then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < <(tail -F -n +1 "$filepath")
```

Then, I rearranged the code by moving the comparison expression into the process substitution to make the code more concise:

```
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < <(tail -F -n +1 "$filepath" | grep '^!')
```

Sadly, it doesn't work as expected; nothing is printed to the terminal (stdout).

I prefer to write `grep ^\!` after `tail`. Why doesn't the second code snippet work? Why putting the command pipe into the process substitution make things different?

PS1. This is how I manually produce the gradually growing file by randomly executing one of the following commands:

```
echo ' something' >> "$filepath"
echo '!something' >> "$filepath"
```

PS2. Test under `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release` and `tail (GNU coreutils) 8.25`.

Comment: @iBug Wow. Thanks for the feedback. I re-tried the above code carefully, and it still does work. I am using GNU Bash of version 4.3.48(1)-release on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: for second version, can you try `grep --line-buffered` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858912/piping-tail-output-though-grep-twice

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks. Your comment is sightly earlier than iBug's post.

Comment: Unbelievable... It actually has nothing to do with `tail -F`, which confused me for quire some time before figuring out that it's `grep`'s fault.

Comment: @Sundeep you beat me to it. Your comment turns out to be the correct answer.

Comment: the duplicate is about *grep twice*. maybe change title with "Piping tail output though grep"? @Sundeep

Comment: @kyodev yeah, the duplicate question's title could be bettered.. though not sure what'd be best... the issue is not restricted to grep alone... it would happen whenever tail -f/F output is processed by a tool (that doesn't do line-buffering) and is then passed on to another process..

Comment: yes, iBug said that wel: "grep is not line-buffered when its stdout isn't connected to a tty". in fact, it's the duplicate title that should be changed, **twice** or more is not important. here the title could also be improved, imho @Sundeep

Comment: @kyodev Thanks. I changed the title for programmers who will face the similar situation to search more easily with the following keywords: **no output**, `tail`, and `grep`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` is not line-buffered when its stdout isn't connected to a tty. So it's trying to process a block (usually 4 KiB or 8 KiB or so) before generating some output.

You need to tell `grep` to buffer its output by line. If you're using GNU grep, this works:

```
done < <(tail -F -n +1 "$filepath" | grep '^!' --line-buffered)
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```