# Bash tail command and multiple pipes

Tags: bash, pipe

I am currently facing a problem with the command

```
while sleep 0.3; do echo "1"; done | tail -n +3 | grep --line-buffered "1"
```

I wanted an output that looks like:

```
[nothing during 0.6s]
1
1
...
```

but had:

```
[nothing forever]
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13858912/4810787) and read [this blog post](https://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) but as the `--line-buffered` option is set for `grep`, I think this is not a buffering problem. My researches did not led me to other solutions, I hope I did not miss something obvious.

I am using `zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` if it is important.

Comment: The output from `tail` is buffered.

Comment: The `--line-buffered` option is only useful if you're piping the output of `grep` to something that needs to see it immediately. Since you're not piping that output, it's not helpful here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Barmar mentioned in the comments, this is getting swallowed up in a [4KB stdio buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/72681). You can use `unbuffer -p` to avoid it:

```
while sleep 0.3; do echo "1"; done | unbuffer -p tail -n +3 | grep 1
```

Or you could also use `stdbuf` in line-buffering mode:

```
while sleep 0.3; do echo "1"; done | stdbuf -oL tail -n +3 | grep 1
```

Comment: It solved my problem. I should have read the blog post totally instead of searching quickly information in it. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, the data is held up in a 4k glibc stdio output buffer, and not in the 64k pipe buffer

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks, rephrasing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the actual situation, you might be able to avoid the problem (caused by the pipe from `tail` to `grep`) by doing everything with a single more powerful tool, like `awk`:

```
while sleep 0.3; do echo "1"; done | awk 'NR > 2 && /1/'
```

But of course, if you need to pipe the output from `awk` into something else, you just have the same problem all over again. But if your version of `awk` supports it, you can explicitly flush output:

```
while sleep 0.3; do echo "1"; done | awk 'NR > 2 && /1/ {print $0; fflush()}' | | while read x; do echo "read '$x'"; done
```

...or presumably use `unbuffer -p` or `stdbuf -oL` on `awk` (see @JeffBowman's answer), if you have those (I don't, so I can't test them).

Comment: The command I wrote in my question was simplified, mainly because some of the tools I use are non-standard and I did not want people to have to install additional tools just to test the command. The whole command takes 4 pipes, the last one being a `while read ...` command. Still, this may be a valid solution for others, thank you!

Comment: @Nelimee Hah, I found a way to make it work (with another pipe) in `awk`. Might still be irrelevant for your situation, but again it might be useful to others.